# Javascript bugs in event handling

Tags: javascript, events, focus, blur, jquery-trigger

I am trying to write a script which fill data(after i run the code in chrome console) in the registration form of a website.

I want a function in pure javascript which exactly work like a jquery function. See the code

Javascript:

```
var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName');
var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
var event2 = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  event.initEvent('focus', true,false);
  lastName.dispatchEvent(event);
  lastName.value = 'Khan';
  event2.initEvent('blur');
  lastName.dispatchEvent(event2);
```

JQuery:

```
$('#lastName').focus();
$('#lastName').val("lastName");
$('#lastName').blur();
```

The problem is that JavaScript actually does not focus the field, where jQuery focus the field.
So because of that when i try to submit the form it doesn't validate.

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, there's no need to focus on an `<input>` to be able to set its value.

Comment: yeah but if i didn't focus on it, the field doesn't validate @ChrisG

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're setting up events ? you could simply use the normal HTMLInputElement method `focus`, right?

Comment: `lastName.focus(); lastName.value = 'Khan'; lastName.blur();`

Comment: @zfrisch i am running this code on a web form [link](https://profil.tlen.pl/rejestracja/) but it give validation error.  CODE:                         `// first name
  var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
  var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
  var event2 = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    event.initEvent('focus', true,false);
    firstName.dispatchEvent(event);
    firstName.value = 'Aliya';
    event2.initEvent('blur',true,false);
    firstName.dispatchEvent(event2);`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use lastName.focus() if you need the event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focus

Comment: it returns undefined value.        `var firstName = document.getElementById('firstName');
  firstName.focus();`

Comment: thanks for your time sir, but i already check that before not so helpful in my case

Comment: i want a javascript function that focuses on a field

Comment: line 4 in the js sets focus on the field; perhaps if you could elaborate a bit further on your requirement we can get you sorted

Comment: the field(input password/text field) i write code for does not get focus in real time(cursor does not show in that filed with `fieldName.focus();` as how it does with JQuery `$('fieldName')).focus();` ) JS `focus()` method just invoke the focus event but JQuery `focus()` method actually does focus on the selected field.    **what i want to say is how can i bring cursor to that field with JS code.** I have tried every way possible with `focus()` event. **is there any other event that could work for me?** **

Comment: **_Note:_** i don't need onfocus() event which actually calls after someone manually(with mouse or keyboard) focus that field.

Comment: I can't quite understand what you're asking for; the JS .focus() as in the orginal fiddle puts the cursor in to that text input -updated fiddle to demonstrate cursor switching between fields https://jsfiddle.net/osmqoy5b/4/

Comment: yeah.. but it doesn't work as XSS, consider this [form.](https://profil.tlen.pl/rejestracja/)

Comment: thats right i have explained my question a bit ambiguous but i guess now you would understand what i am trying to do.